# Is there an inverse function for F[x] = {Cos[x], Sin[x]} in Mathematica?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

Mathematica has functions `ArcCos`, `ArcSin`, and `ArcTan`, but none of these does what I need, which is, given two real numbers a and b, at least one of them being nonzero, to find the angle x such that

`{Cos[x], Sin[x]} == {a,b}/Sqrt[a^2+b^2]`.

Is there a simple way to build such a function? Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's a reason why I'm not called bobthemathematician, but how about rolling your own?  `Solve[{Cos[x] == a/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], Sin[x] == b/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]}, x]`

Comment: `ArcTan[a, b]` does what you want.

Comment: ArcTan[a,b] is the best answer in terms of efficiency but was entered as a comment so it could not be accepted. The answer by HaoLiang and Kuba also works and provides good insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
Arg[#1 + I*#2] &[a, b]
```

Comment: How is this different from `ArcTan[#1,#2]&[a,b]`?